# best way to validate that my hazelcast xml config file was picked up

Tags: java, hazelcast

I want to figure out the best way of confirming that my specified hazelcast config XML file was picked up (and not the hazelcast-default config).  Right now, I am using the build metthod on the XmlClientConfigBuilder for the client setup and FileSystemXmlConfig for the server setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply print/log out the properties from the xml config file like this:

**for client config**

```
config.getNetworkConfig().getConnectionTimeout(); //where config -> ClientConfig
```

**Server**

```
config.getNetworkConfig().getPort();  //where config is Config
```

Answer (score 1):

In Hazelcast 3.3 the logging which configuration file is loaded, is improved extensively and it will show which file is being picked up. This week Hazelcast 3.3 is going to be released.

If you are using an older version; one trick is to set e.g. a custom groupname for example and once the HazelcastInstance is loaded, just read out that groupname and make sure it is the expected value.